# Selecting only N records from layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, features, select

I would like to join attributes by location of 2 layers. My INPUT layer has 446k records and it is too many. I would like to divide my layer and select for example 10000 records.

For example in Python if I have a list I can select by data[:10000]. How can I select x records from layer?

My code:

```py
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProcessingFeedback, QgsRasterLayer

sys.path.append('/usr/lib/qgis')
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')
os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM"] = "offscreen"

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'/usr/bin/qgis', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

processing.run("native:joinattributesbylocation", {
                'INPUT': r'/home/gis/budynki_opolskie/budynki_opolskie/bdot10k_bubd_a_opolskie.gpkg|layername=bubd_a',
                'JOIN': r'/home/gis/adresypolska/PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA.shp',
                'PREDICATE': [1,5],
                'JOIN_FIELDS': ['PNA','SIMC_id','SIMC_nazwa','ULIC_nazwa','Numer'],
                'METHOD': 0,
                'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': True,
                'PREFIX': '',
                'OUTPUT': r'/home/gis/zlaczoneopolskie.shp'
                })
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented?

Comment: The code joins attributes of 2 layers, but first layer has 446k records and it takes too much time. I would like to select 10000 records from my first layer and then run code.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be a direct way of doing that, but PyQGIS API let's us to achieve it in an easy way:

```py
def selectLimitedByCount(layer, count):
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)
    request.setNoAttributes()  # We only go for feature ids
    request.setLimit(count)
    layer.select([f.id() for f in layer.getFeatures(request)])

selectLimitedByCount(iface.activeLayer(), 10000)
```

---

By and large, [`QgsFeatureRequest`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Feature/QgsFeatureRequest.html) allows us to configure queries to vector data providers, just like if we were creating `SELECT` statements in SQL. In this case, the `SQL` `LIMIT` keyword can be set via PyQGIS in this way:

```
request.setLimit(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some general steps using pyqgis:

1. Create vector layer of your bubd_a layer
2. Create an memory vector layer ([q/a](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173936/how-to-create-memory-layer-and-populate-fields))
3. Loop through the features in the vector layer object using .getFeatures() ([help doc](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#iterating-over-a-subset-of-features)) method with a counter and add each feature to the memory layer
4. Once you hit 10K interval, call the processing.run() statement using the 10K memory layer
5. Repeat step 2-4

Comment: Point 2 is too old. Could you show me how will looks the code?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the ["Random selection"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#random-selection) tool for *selecting N random features*.

```py
import processing
from qgis.utils import iface

layer = iface.activeLayer()

processing.run("qgis:randomselection", {
                    'INPUT' : layer,
                    'METHOD' : 0,
                    'NUMBER' : 5 -- specify a number here
                    })
```

To get more information about this algorithm, please run the following command `processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:randomselection")` in the Python Console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).

---

**References:**

- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook » 21. Cheat sheet for PyQGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/cheat_sheet.html#cheat-sheet-for-pyqgis)

Answer (score 0):

I solved that in another way, in my opinion easier way. I recommend to use Geopandas and add something like that:

```
opolskie = geopandas.read_file(r'/home/gis/budynki_opolskie/budynki_opolskie/bdot10k_bubd_a_opolskie.gpkg', layer ='bubd_a')
maleopolskie = opolskie[:10001]
maleopolskie.to_file("maleopolskie.shp")


processing.run("native:joinattributesbylocation", {'INPUT':r'/home/gis/maleopolskie.shp|layername=maleopolskie',
                                                   'JOIN':r'/home/gis/adresypolska/PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA.shp',
                                                   'PREDICATE':[1,5],
                                                   'JOIN_FIELDS':['PNA','SIMC_id','SIMC_nazwa','ULIC_nazwa','Numer'],
                                                   'METHOD':0,
                                                   'DISCARD_NONMATCHING':True,
                                                   'PREFIX':'',
                                                   'OUTPUT':r'/home/gis/opolskiegeo.shp'})
```